# Perl modules not recognized

Tags: perl, ubuntu, bioinformatics, cpan

I'm trying to run unitas_1.7.8.pl, a [bioinformatic software available here](https://www.smallrnagroup.uni-mainz.de/). Importantly, I've used this software many times in the past successfully on this ubuntu machine. Now when I run the command

```
perl ~/scripts/unitas_1.7.0.pl -threads 24 -s homo_sapiens -i PCR_Primer_11_S11_L001_R1_001.trim.lng ...
```

I get the error

```
Perl module LWP::Simple is not installed on this machine!
Perl module Archive::Extract (in core since 2007-07-07) is not installed on this machine!
Perl modules are available for download at http://www.cpan.org/

If you have CPAN installed try the following:
 cpan
 install Archive::Extract
 exit

If you are on MAC or UNIX you should run cpan with sudo:
 sudo cpan
 install Archive::Extract
 exit
```

I've followed those instructions and updated AND reinstalled cpan (even though I know it should be fine) without apparent issues. The only thing I can think of that has changed since the last time I successfully used unitas is that the server was hard-rebooted a month ago.

Details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
$ cpan --version
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
/home/user/miniconda3/bin/cpan version 1.64 calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.12 [paranoid]),
running under Perl version 5.30.3.
  [Now continuing due to backward compatibility and excessive paranoia.
   See 'perldoc Getopt::Std' about $Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION.]
Nothing to install!

$ type -p perl; perl -M5.010 -e'say "$_: $ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/, keys(%ENV)'; echo 'o conf' | cpan
/home/stewart/miniconda3/bin/perl
[...]
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
    makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]
[...]
$ perl -MLWP::Simple -E 'say $INC{"LWP/Simple.pm"}'
Can't locate LWP/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::Simple module) (@INC contains: /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.30.3 /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/5.30.3 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
$ head -n 1 "$( type -p cpan )"
#!/home/stewart/miniconda3/bin/perl
$ perl -MLWP::Simple -e'print "ok\n"'
Can't locate LWP/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::Simple module) (@INC contains: /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.30.3 /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/stewart/miniconda3/lib/5.30.3 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

current state of LWP::Simple and Archive::Extract

```
$ sudo cpan install LWP::Simple
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 07 Sep 2021 08:55:47 GMT
LWP::Simple is up to date (6.56).
$ sudo cpan install Archive::Extract
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 07 Sep 2021 08:55:47 GMT
Archive::Extract is up to date (0.88).
$ sudo cpan LWP::Simple
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 07 Sep 2021 08:55:47 GMT
LWP::Simple is up to date (6.56).
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `type -p perl; perl -M5.010 -e'say "$_: $ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/, keys(%ENV)'; echo 'o conf' | cpan`

Comment: *"I've followed those instructions and updated AND reinstalled cpan ..."* : They don't ask you to reinstall `cpan`, but to install the modules `LWP::Simple` and `Archive::Extract`. Did you try that?

Comment: I've added the output as requested by @ikegami and I did try installing each of those modules individually as well, but they all came back saying they were correctly installed already.

Comment: *".. they all came back saying they were correctly installed already"* : What is the output of `perl -MLWP::Simple -E 'say $INC{"LWP/Simple.pm"}'`

Comment: One more: `head -n 1 "$( type -p cpan )"`

Comment: Oh, and does  `perl -MLWP::Simple -e'print "ok\n"'` give an error?

Comment: See requested output. Thanks again for your help. @ikegami

Comment: hmm? Did you forget to add it?

Comment: I don't think the edit saved properly. I confirmed that it is there now! How does that output look @ikegami

Comment: Well, every sign points to LWP:Simple not being installed. Confirmed that `cpan` is using the right `perl`. What does `cpan LWP::Simple` say?

Comment: Added a section in the end of the post with the output of install. It looks like the modules are installed but when I run the command I still get an error saying they are not installed. Its like perl is looking in the wrong place when called. Is that possible? Does it have something to do with using miniconda? @ikegami

Comment: It's missing again

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It is there under "current state of LWP::Simple and Archive::Extract"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions suggested worked for me except calling perl directly from another directory (which already had it installed).

```
/usr/bin/perl5.30.0 ~/scripts/unitas_1.7.0.pl ...
```

There may be a way to switch the default perl used when called to this directory with $PATH, but I found this workaround for now. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have Miniconda, then you should install using the Bioconda channel in an isolated environment. Your Perl installation, from conda, is interfering with your system CPAN modules:

```
conda create -n unitas -c bioconda unitas
conda activate unitas

unitas.pl -threads 24 -s homo_sapiens -i PCR_Primer_11_S11_L001_R1_001.trim.lng ...

conda deactivate
```

Comment: This actually didn't work for me, I got the same error as before even in a conda environment. I'm assuming that there would be a way to troubleshoot within conda, had I tried installing the modules or something.
What did work was calling the system perl like this:    
/usr/bin/perl5.30.0 ~/scripts/unitas_1.7.0.pl ...